# NLog 5 ignores Logging.LogLevel.Default option

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, nlog

I'm trying to configure NLog for a .NET 6 console app using the following **appsettings.json**:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "NLog": {
    "targets": {
      "console": {
        "type": "Console",
        "layout": "${longdate} ${pad:padding=5:inner=${uppercase:${level}}} ${message}${onexception:inner=${newline}${exception:format=ToString}}"
      }
    },
    "rules": [
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "writeTo": "console",
        "minLevel": "Trace"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```cs
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
    {
        var configuration = context.Configuration.GetSection("NLog");
        if (!configuration.Exists())
            return;

        LogManager.Configuration = new NLogLoggingConfiguration(configuration);
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.AddNLog();
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<MyHostedService>();
    })
    .Build()
    .Run();
```

The following code of the `MyHostedService` works as expected with [NLog.Extensions.Logging 1.7.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging/1.7.5) - only messages at the `Information` level and higher are displayed in the console.

```cs
private readonly ILogger<MyHostedService> _logger;

public MyHostedService(ILogger<MyHostedService> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _logger.LogTrace("Test");
    _logger.LogDebug("Test");
    _logger.LogInformation("Test");
    _logger.LogWarning("Test");
    _logger.LogError("Test");
    _logger.LogCritical("Test");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

But if [5.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging/5.2.0) is installed then it outputs all messages. What am I doing wrong? Does [NLog.Extensions.Logging 5.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging/5.2.0) package require additional settings to consider `Logging.LogLevel.Default` configuration option value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NLog v5 includes [several breaking changes](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html) where one is [NLog.Extensions.Logging without any filter](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html#nlogextensionslogging-without-any-filter)

You can do this:

```json
  "NLog": {
    "targets": {
      "console": {
        "type": "Console",
        "layout": "${longdate} ${pad:padding=5:inner=${uppercase:${level}}} ${message}${onexception:inner=${newline}${exception:format=ToString}}"
      }
    },
    "rules": [
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "finalMinLevel": "Info"
      },
      {
        "logger": "Microsoft*",
        "finalMinLevel": "Warn"
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "writeTo": "console",
        "minLevel": "Trace"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Or you can do this:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning"
    },
    "NLog": {
      "RemoveLoggerFactoryFilter": false
    }
  },
  "NLog": {
    "targets": {
      "console": {
        "type": "Console"
      }
    },
    "rules": [
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "writeTo": "console",
        "minLevel": "Trace"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json

Comment: Thank you, Rolf. The second way also requires to use another overload of the [`AddNLog()`](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v5.0.0/html/M_NLog_Extensions_Logging_ConfigureExtensions_AddNLog.htm) method and pass `context.Configuration` to it.